# Eclipse CDT .project file loses all linked resources 50% of the time

Tags: eclipse

I have an Eclipse CDT project (actually STM32Cube IDE but it's 2019 Eclipse Equinox under the hood) in which the `.project` file contains all linked resources, since the source files are not inside the project.  This works fine if I leave it alone.

However, during continuous integration I need to re-import a fresh project each time and I find that, 50% of the time, Eclipse loses track of all of the linked resources from the `.project` file and the build fails immediately.

If I delete the project and re-import it, it will work fine the first time but on the next build it will fail.  Since this is continuous integration I just delete the build and try again, which works but it's quite a waste of time, and looks rather a mess, to have every other build fail.

I can't spot the thing that is causing Eclipse to lose its mind: forcing a clean build and switching the indexer off doesn't make a difference.

Has anyone out there seen this kind of behaviour and found a fix for it?

Comment: Have you opened a bug report?

Comment: I've asked the same question on the ST forums but I wasn't quite sure where to open the bug report: with ST or with Eclipse?  I'll plump for one and see what happens.